# installed `default-jdk` but there is no `javac`

Tags: debian

I have a Debian Unstable VM which I used to package a Java project before. Today, the `javac` was gone somehow, so I installed `default-jdk` again. But still, there is no `javac`.

What could I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`javac` is managed by the [alternatives system](http://wiki.debian.org/DebianAlternatives). `/usr/bin/javac` is a symbolic link to `/etc/alternatives/javac` which is a symbolic link to one of the Java compilers you have installed. The `default-jdk` package depends on `openjdk-6-jdk` which provides `/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/bin/javac` (on i386). This file is what `/etc/alternatives/javac` should link to. If it doesn't, run

```
update-alternatives --config javac
```

to configure the target of `/etc/alternatives/javac` interactively, or `update-alternatives --auto javac` to reset it to its default value.

Comment: I tried running `update-alternatives --config javac`, but it gave me `update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for javac.`. I just created the symlink by hand.

Answer (score 1):

Check your `$PATH` environment variable to check if it contains `/usr/lib/java/bin` or `/usr/lib64/java/bin` on x86_64 systems. This variable is usually when you log in set via a shell script that the jdk package installs; it may help to log out and back in again. Check the value of `$JAVA_HOME`.

If your PATH does contain the path I mentioned, and `type javac` still doesn't give you anything, then try typing `locate bin/javac` and see what that returns. You may have to run `sudo updatedb` or `sudo locate -u` beforehand, if you just installed the package, so that the slocate database is up do date.