# Unable to build using Java OpenJDK 14. /bin/sh: javac: command not found

Tags: bash, centos, environment-variables, make, java

I've been tasked to work on updating a Java program that hasn't been touched for years and I'm running into issues building it using the latest version of Java OpenJDK 14.0.1.7-2 on Centos 7. When I run the `$ make all` command to start compiling the Java program I get a `/bin/sh: javac: command not found` error message.

I've edited the `.bash_profile` file in my home directory and added:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-14-openjdk-14.0.1.7-2.rolling.el7.x86_64/bin/java
```

Followed by: `$ source .bash_profile` to make the changes take effect and verified using `echo $JAVA_HOME` which gives me the expected output, but still no luck.

So far I'm only able to successfully build the program when Java OpenJDK 1.8 is installed along with with the additional javac repository.

Running the `alternatives --display javac` I get this on the final line:

```
Current `best' version is /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk 1.7.0.261-2.6.22.2.el7_8.x86_64/bin/javac.
```

This is strange to me as I have not installed Java OpenJDK V1.7 on my system

Running the `alternatives --display java` I get this on the final line:

```
Current `best' version is /usr/lib/jvm/java-14-openjdk-14.0.1.7-2.rolling.el7.x86_64/bin/java.
```

Any suggestions on where I'm going wrong would be much appreciated.

Comment: You can help answerers by putting the outputs of `alternatives --display java` and `alternatives --display javac` in your question.  A related question is https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/598351/5132 .

Comment: Keep in mind, you need the java-latest-devel package if you want javac.

Comment: Thanks for responding @JdeBP so by running your first command the final output message is `Current best version is /usr/lib/jvm/java-14-openjdk-14.0.1.7-2.rolling.el7.x86_64/bin/java` which is what I'm expecting as it's the only version of Java I have installed, however with your second command I get `Current best version is /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.261-2.6.22.2.el7_8.x86_64/bin/javac` which is odd as Java OpenJDK v1.7 was removed from my system using the Yum Extender package manager

Comment: Thanks for responding @jsbillings I have `java-latest-openjdk` , `java-latest-openjdk-devel` and `java-latest-openjdk-headless`  installed on my system and all of these packages are referring to  the OpenJDK development tools 14

Comment: In the question, not in comments.  It's not legible in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things, i noticed in your JAVA_HOME environment variable you have the path to an actual bin, try changing that to this:

`JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-14-openjdk-14.0.1.7-2.rolling.el7.x86_64/`

You might wish to check the PATH environment variable too, use the following command:

`find /bin/ /sbin/ /usr/sbin /usr/lib /usr/bin/ /usr/local/bin /usr/local/sbin ${HOME}/ /opt/ -type f -name 'javac' -exec dirname "{}" \;`

IF that finds something export PATH=${PATH}:whatever-result-you-get-from-that or simply:

`export PATH=${PATH}:$(find /bin/ /sbin/ /usr/sbin /usr/lib /usr/bin/ /usr/local/bin /usr/local/sbin ${HOME}/ /opt/ -type f -name 'javac' -exec dirname "{}" \;)`

Comment: `JAVA_HOME` is always the path without the `bin` directory, e.g.
`export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-14-openjdk-14.0.1.7-2.rolling.el7.x86_64` and `export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH`

Comment: Thanks for responding @linuxgeek I've updated my `JAVA_HOME` as you listed and added the export `PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH` below. There was already an `export PATH` line  in the `.bash_profile`. Is it ok to have two different lines of `export` path? Additionally your `find` command returned no results before and after I updated my environment variables.

Comment: Yes, it is fine to have multiple PATH lines, the PATH env var i listed takes the old path and adds on to it.  Just make sure the second one that includes that path is after the first one.  As for the find I was only checking in bin directories, adjust the find command  to have /usr/lib/ and it would return the path to javac but it looks like you're getting it figured out.

Answer (score 0):

That the alternative for `javac` points to something that you say isn't currently installed indicates that the simplest answer is to update the alternative so that it points to a JDK that *is* installed.
This will re-point the symbolic links so that `/usr/bin/javac` points to an actual executable again, and a `PATH` search for `javac` will work once more.
No actual `PATH` change is needed.

```
alternatives --config javac
```

is the interactive way to do this, or alternatively

```
alternatives --auto javac
```

## Further reading

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/25432/5132